# Custom color palette for scale_fill_fermenter()

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, colors

I'm using ggplot2's `scale_fill_fermenter()` for a discrete colorbar legend. Colors can be specified under the `palette` argument, however only a limited set of color palettes seem to be available (those from `RColorBrewer::display.brewer.all()`).

Is there a way to define a custom color palette? The trivial solution of passing a vector of color names/hex does not work ...

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scale_fill_fermenter` is a wrapper which returns

```
binned_scale(aesthetics, "fermenter", 
  binned_pal(brewer_pal(type, palette, direction)), 
  na.value = na.value, guide = guide, ...)
```

If it's fine for you to call the non-exported function `ggplot2:::binned_pal` you can use this code as a template to write a custom `scale_fill_fermenter` function which allows for custom color palettes and may look like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)

v <- ggplot(faithfuld) +
  geom_tile(aes(waiting, eruptions, fill = density))

# Custom palette
pal <- scales::hue_pal()(8)

scale_fill_fermenter_custom <- function(pal, na.value = "grey50", guide = "coloursteps", aesthetics = "fill", ...) {
  binned_scale("fill", "fermenter", ggplot2:::binned_pal(scales::manual_pal(unname(pal))), na.value = na.value, guide = guide, ...)  
}

v + scale_fill_fermenter_custom(pal)
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks for your quick but elaborate answer!! :)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same problem and I found this solution:

1. You have to overwrite `scale_fill_fermenter()` (or create your function), where in `binned_scale()` you'll not call `palette = pal_binned(pal_brewer(type, palette, direction))` but you'll call your function `ggplot2:::binned_pal(brewer_my_pal(type = type, palette = palette, direction = direction))`.

   ```r
   scale_fill_fermenter <- function(..., type = "seq", palette = 1, direction = -1, na.value = "grey50", guide = "coloursteps", aesthetics = "fill") {
         type <- rlang::arg_match0(type, c("seq", "div", "qual"))
         if (type == "qual") {
           cli::cli_warn(c(
             "Using a discrete colour palette in a binned scale",
             "i" = "Consider using {.code type = \"seq\"} or {.code type = \"div\"} instead"
           ))
         }
         binned_scale(aesthetics, "fermenter", ggplot2:::binned_pal(brewer_my_pal(type = type, palette = palette, direction = direction)), na.value = na.value, guide = guide, ...)
       }
   ```
2. Then you `build brewer_my_pal()` on this way:

   ```r
   brewer_my_pal = function (palette = "Blue", type = "seq", direction = 1, ...)
   {
     force(direction)
     function(n) {
       if (n < 3) {
         pal <- suppressWarnings(build_my_palette(name = palette,  n = n, type = "continuous"))
       }
       else {
         pal <- build_my_palette(name = palette,  n = n, type = "continuous")
       }
       pal <- pal[seq_len(n)]
       if (direction == -1) {
         pal <- rev(pal)
       }
       pal
     }
   }
   ```
3. `brewer_my_pal()` call another your function, then build it:

   ```r
   build_my_palette = function(name, n, type = c("discrete", "continuous"), direction = 1) {
     if(is.character(name) && length(name) == 1)
     {
       # In this way we can continue to use the palettes from the package RColorBrewer and the old code doesn't need to be changed
       if(name %in% row.names(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal.info))
       {
         palette = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n = n, name)
       }else
       {
         stop("name has to be a pallete's name from the package RColorBrewer")
       }
     }else if(is.character(name) && length(name) > 1)
     {
       palette = name
     }else if(is.numeric(name))
     {
       # select the number oƒ the palette
       palette = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n = n, row.names(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal.info[name,]))
     }else
     {
       stop("name has to be a character for the name of palette or a vector of colors")
     }
     if (missing(n)) {
       n = length(palette)
     }else if(n > length(palette) & type == "discrete")
     {
       warning(paste("n too large, allowed maximum for palette", 
               name, "is", length(palette)), 
               "\nReturning the palette you asked for with some colors repeated\n")
     }
     type = match.arg(type)
     if (direction == -1) {
       palette <- rev(palette)
     }
     out = switch(type,
                  continuous = grDevices::colorRampPalette(palette)(n),
                  discrete = rep(palette,n/length(palette) +1)[1:n] # repeat the palette until the length is n 
     )
     structure(out, name = name, class = "palette")
   ```

Now you can pass a string or a number if you want to call an RColorBrewer's palettes, while if you'll pass a character's vector it will build and will use your palette (like `c("red", "blue", "green")` or `c("#04e762", "#f5b700", "#00a1e4", "#89fc00", "#dc0073")`.

Example:

```
v <- ggplot(faithfuld) +  geom_tile(aes(waiting, eruptions, fill = density))
v + scale_fill_fermenter(palette = c("#04e762", "#f5b700", "#00a1e4", "#dc0073"), direction = -1)
```

[image: The example's plot]