# Specify bin colours in binned colour/fill scales

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider the following plot using `scale_fill_gradientn()` where I specify the colours manually...

```r
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(faithfuld) +
  geom_tile(aes(waiting, eruptions, fill = density))

p+  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("white","red","blue","green"),
                         limits=c(0,0.04))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Apologies for the (deliberately) ugly colour scheme.

Now, I would much prefer to have this as binned colours, which can now be done using `scale_fill_stepsn()` like so.

```r
p+  scale_fill_stepsn(colours=c("white","red","blue","green"),
                      breaks=seq(0.01,0.03,by=0.01),
                      limits=c(0,0.04))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

However, you can see that the binned colours that have been chosen are interpolated. Instead I would like to specify them explicitly, so that e.g. [0.00,0.01] is explicitly white, [0.01,0.02] is red etc... How can I do this?

Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative solution I found, based on the answer to this question:

[Custom color palette for scale_fill_fermenter()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64013935/custom-color-palette-for-scale-fill-fermenter)

The code is essentially just a rejigging of the code underlying `scale_fill_fermenter()`, but using `manual_pal()` to specify the colour palette directly.

```r
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(faithfuld) +
  geom_tile(aes(waiting, eruptions, fill = density))

p+  binned_scale("fill",
                 "foo",
                 ggplot2:::binned_pal(scales::manual_pal(c("white","red","blue","green"))),
                 guide="coloursteps",
                 breaks=seq(0.01,0.03,by=0.01),
                 limits=c(0,0.04),
                 show.limits=TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no `scale_*_binned_manual()`, so I'm afraid you'd have to set the `values` argument of the scale manually. Because the `scale_fill_stepsn()` function takes the midpoint between breaks as the point where the colour is interpolated (in transformed space), you can make sure that your colours fall exactly on these midpoints.

```r
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(faithfuld) +
  geom_tile(aes(waiting, eruptions, fill = density))


p+  scale_fill_stepsn(colours=c("white","red","blue","green"),
                      breaks=seq(0.01,0.03,by=0.01),
                      limits=c(0,0.04),
                      values = scales::rescale(c(0.005, 0.015, 0.025, 0.035), 
                                               from = c(0, 0.04)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>