# Problem with creating breaks and setting colors in ggplot maps

Tags: r

I am trying to make a series of maps with the following characteristics:

I want to set bins/colors for tracts$pop.compare as: 0-.75(green), .75-1.25(green), 1.25-2(yellow), 2-3(orange), 3-10(red), 10+(black). I tried the following code, but everything 0-3 is blue, and then 3-10 is yellow, and I'm not sure why that is.

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = tracts, mapping = aes(fill = pop.compare), show.legend = TRUE) +
  scale_fill_stepsn(colours=c("blue", "green", "yellow", "orange", "red", "black"),
                    limits = c(0,227),
                    breaks = c(0.75, 1.25, 2, 3, 10)) + 
  coord_sf()
```

(also, not all bins are filled. Some are empty and no tract has that value, but I'm doing a series of maps, where they will be filled in other versions, and want to keep the legend / values the same. I tried included drop = FALSE, but got an error for unused argument).

[image]

Comment: Without data can't check this myself, but would the use of values = scales::rescales() help as in solution 2 from this question ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65627153/specify-bin-colours-in-binned-colour-fill-scales

Comment: Dumb question, I am sure: but I get how to post pseudo code for non-spatial data (e.g. col1 = c(....), df = data.frame(col1....)), but what do you do for spatial data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update based on @stomper

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = tracts, mapping = aes(fill = pop.compare), show.legend = TRUE) +
  scale_fill_stepsn(colours=c("blue", "green", "yellow", "orange", "red", "black"),
                    limits = c(0,227),
                    breaks = c(0.75, 1.25, 2, 3, 10),
                    values = scales::rescale(c(0.375, 1, 1.625, 2.5, 6.5, 118.5))) + 
  coord_sf()
```

this (sort of) works. I mean, it works on the more complicated version I have. But for the version I posted, and the edits above, for some reasons green is duplicating, and therefore black is falling off. I'm guessing its a typo somewhere in the values

Comment: In your text you duplicated green.  "I want to set bins/colors for tracts$pop.compare as: 0-.75(green), .75-1.25(green), " So if you copied that from your code, it may indicate the reason why you have duplicates.